# CSS transform rotation on :after not working

Tags: html, css

I've styled a checkbox and wanted to make a checkmark with the :after element. However, I can not turn it around. The same style attached to a div works fine.

Used style:

```
content: '';
position: absolute;
width:.5em;
height:.2em;
transition: all .2s;
border-left: 2px solid red;
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
top: 0.4em;
left: 0.3em;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

See a Codepen here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Haukebr/pen/KWxONp)

Comment: The :after is attached to the label, not the input itself

Comment: That's why you should put the [MCVE] in the question itself - from the question it sounds like you've tried to style the checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple transform overrides the previous `transform`. Better to write them as shorthand

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
```

Comment: Thats the error. Thank you very much! Even the Dev-console showed the rotate... strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.wb_checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

.wb_checkbox>input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wb_checkbox>input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
 
}

.wb_checkbox>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #65a416), color-stop(1, #6ca43d));
  /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #65a416 0%, #6ca43d 100%);*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.wb_checkbox>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 13px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5>Choose Option *</h5>
    <p class="wb_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" checked>
      <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
      <strong>I have not car !</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="wb_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
      <label for="checkbox-2"></label>
      <strong>I have car</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a straight edged checkmark. The Text based one does not work for this.